# What does "I am all for people looking good, but some people take it way too far." mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

> Always remember: Dress for the job you want, not the job you have. I
>   can't stand to see the way some people dress for work these days. It's
>   criminal. **I am all for people looking good, but some people take it
>   way too far.** If anyone comes into my office in sneakers, or ripped
>   clothing, or attire that looks like it belongs in a nightclub, I just
>   can't take him seriously.

The above paragraph is under the title of **How to dress and Groom for work**. I cannot fully understand the meaning of the bold sentence in it.

Does it mean that the writer supports dressing properly at work or likes people who dress properly at work,  but the way that some people dress is too strange and too far away from office dress?

How should I understand the phrase people looking good here?

Answer (score 2):

I think you understand the paragraph correctly.

The writer expresses approval for people dressing in a way that matches the job they are applying for. E.g. a business suit and tie for a man wanting to work in a bank's front office, or sturdy footwear and a waterproof jacket when wanting to work as a gardener. The writer also expresses that some people take looking good too far, so it may be wrong to wear a business suit and tie when wanting to work as a gardener.

The final sentence (i.e. *"If anyone ..."*) also expresses that people should not "under dress", so wearing gardeners clothes when wanting to work in a bank would be wrong.

There is another problem with the final *"If anyone ..."* sentence. The word *"him"* clashes with the rest of the paragraph. The word "*"him"* is specific to males whereas all the other words include both male and female. Changing *"him"* to *"them"* would resolve this point.